# Card is shrinking instead of getting stacked

Tags: css

I have some cards looking like the following:

[image: web]

The problem is that on mobile, they shrink, and they don't pile up as expected. How is it possible to fix this?

This is the CSS:

```
.card__like {
    width: 18px;
}

.card__clock {
    width: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
    fill: #AD7D52;
}
.card__time {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #AD7D52;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.card__clock-info {
    float: right;
}

.card__img {
  visibility: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 235px;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  
}

.card__info-hover {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.card__img--hover {
  transition: 0.2s all ease-out;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
    height: 235px;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
border-top-right-radius: 12px;
top: 0;
  
}
.card-homework {
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0, 1);
  background-color: var(--bg);
    width: 33.3%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 13px 10px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0,0.1);
}
.card-homework:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 30px 18px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0,0.1);
    transform: scale(1.10, 1.10);
}

.card__info {
z-index: 2;
  background-color: var(--bg);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
   padding: 16px 24px 24px 24px;
}

.card__category {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500;
  color: #868686;
}

.card__title {
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: var(--text);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.card__by {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: var(--text);
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.card__author {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #AD7D52;
}

.card-homework:hover .card__img--hover {
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.card-homework:hover .card__info {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}

.card-homework:hover .card__info-hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I know the code is long, but I'm pretty sure the issue is in the `.card-homework` block. I've no clue on how to make these go on top of each other, because usually, the CSS frameworks have this included.

HTML:

```
<div class="row col-md-12" style="padding-left: 3%">
            @foreach($homeworks as $homework)
            <style>
                .card--{{ $homework->id }} .card__img,
                .card--{{ $homework->id }} .card__img--hover {
                    background-image: url('{{ asset('storage/' . $homework->image)}}');
                }
            </style>

            <article class="card-homework card--{{ $homework->id }} image-first">
                        @if($homework->completed == true)
                        <div class="card__info-hover">
                            <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52"><circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/><path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/></svg>
                        </div>
                        @else

                              <svg height="0" width="0">
                            <g id="pulkstenis">
                              
                              
                              <rect id="minutes" transform="rotate(0 16 17)" x="15.386" y="6.464" width="1.227" height="11.439"/>
                              
                            <rect id="stundas" transform="rotate(0 16 17)" x="15.386" y="10.291" width="1.227" height="7.626"/>
                              
                              <rect id="sekundes" transform="rotate(0 16 17)" x="15.88" y="7.46" fill="#ccc" width="0.24" height="9.83"/>

                              
                             <path d="M15.879,2.531c-8.14,0-14.739,6.599-14.739,14.739c0,8.14,6.599,14.739,14.739,14.739s14.739-6.6,14.739-14.739
                                C30.618,9.13,24.02,2.531,15.879,2.531z M15.879,30.852c-7.511,0-13.6-6.089-13.6-13.6c0-7.511,6.089-13.601,13.6-13.601    c7.511,0,13.6,6.089,13.6,13.601C29.479,24.763,23.391,30.852,15.879,30.852z"/>
                              </g>    
                                  
                            </svg>

                              <svg class="icon-clock clock" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                                <use xlink:href="#pulkstenis"></use>
                            </svg>
                        @endif
                        <div class="card__img"></div>
                            <a href="{{ url('/homework/view/' . $homework->id) }}" class="card_link">
                                <div class="card__img--hover"></div>
                            </a>
                    <div class="card__info">
                        <span class="card__category">Homework</span>
                        <h3 class="card__title">{{ $homework->title}}</h3>
                        <span class="card__by">deadline: <a href="#" class="card__author" title="author">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($homework->duedate)->format('d-m-Y') }}</a></span>
                    </div>
            </article>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

[image: mobile]

Comment: Show the HTML as well.

Comment: @m4n0 added :) please check it out.

Comment: Post the code as if you have a ready demo of it :) At this moment your code is dynamic. Can you make sure you can show the demo exactly like in the image here? Using the code snippet or external: https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: In short, you want to use media queries coupled with making your element to `display:block` width `width:100%`

Comment: Hey, @m4n0 I'm sorry for the delay. I made a pen: https://codepen.io/dlabs/pen/oNbMxyx

Comment: But in your Codepen, it is already in one column.

Comment: @m4n0 oops, just updated it. Check it now please :)

Comment: Do you mean you want it like this? https://codepen.io/Manoj6994/pen/abdjEpq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width: 33.3%` causes the cards to stay in the same row and shrink. You can have it set to 100% only for mobile screen.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .card-homework {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```css
.card__like {
  width: 18px;
}

.card__clock {
  width: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  fill: #AD7D52;
}

.card__time {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #AD7D52;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.card__clock-info {
  float: right;
}

.card__img {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 235px;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
}

.card__info-hover {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.card__img--hover {
  transition: 0.2s all ease-out;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 235px;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  top: 0;
}

.card-homework {
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0, 1);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  width: 33.3%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 13px 10px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


/* Additional code */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .card-homework {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.card-homework:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 30px 18px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transform: scale(1.10, 1.10);
}

.card__info {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: var(--bg);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  padding: 16px 24px 24px 24px;
}

.card__category {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #868686;
}

.card__title {
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: var(--text);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.card__by {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: var(--text);
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.card__author {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #AD7D52;
}

.card-homework:hover .card__img--hover {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.card-homework:hover .card__info {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

.card-homework:hover .card__info-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div id="thisdiv" class="card">
    <div style="padding-top: 2%"></div>
    <div class="row col-md-12" style="padding-left: 3%">
      <style>
        .card--2 .card__img,
        .card--2 .card__img--hover {
          background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/863/500/500.jpg?hmac=k9hZck8HV2PYvXCF5AFoFSaVbSHibjhVO19llHsiaH4');
        }
      </style>

      <article class="card-homework card--2 image-first">
        <div class="card__info-hover">
          <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
                    <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
                    <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8" /></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="card__img"></div>
        <a href="http://homewrk.test/homework/view/2" class="card_link">
          <div class="card__img--hover"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="card__info">
          <span class="card__category">Homework</span>
          <h3 class="card__title">Test</h3>
          <span class="card__by">deadline: <a href="#" class="card__author" title="author">20-06-2020</a></span>
        </div>
      </article>
      <style>
        .card--1 .card__img,
        .card--1 .card__img--hover {
          background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/863/500/500.jpg?hmac=k9hZck8HV2PYvXCF5AFoFSaVbSHibjhVO19llHsiaH4');
        }
      </style>

      <article class="card-homework card--1 image-first">
        <div class="card__info-hover">
          <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
                    <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
                    <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8" /></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="card__img"></div>
        <a href="http://homewrk.test/homework/view/1" class="card_link">
          <div class="card__img--hover"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="card__info">
          <span class="card__category">Homework</span>
          <h3 class="card__title">test</h3>
          <span class="card__by">deadline: <a href="#" class="card__author" title="author">22-06-2020</a></span>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(undefined) {
      var setTime = function() {
        var date = new Date(),
          MINUTE = 60,
          HOUR = 60 * MINUTE,
          seconds = date.getSeconds(),
          minutes = (date.getMinutes() * MINUTE) + seconds,
          hours = (date.getHours() * HOUR) + minutes;
        document.getElementById('sekundes').setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + 360 * (seconds / MINUTE) + ',16,17)');
        document.getElementById('minutes').setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + 360 * (minutes / HOUR) + ',16,17)');
        document.getElementById('stundas').setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + 360 * (hours / (12 * HOUR)) + ',16,17)');
      }
      setTime();
      var interval = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
    })();
  </script>
```